# PHP Nested call_user_func_array with classes

Tags: php, class, callback, call-user-func-array

I have a complicated scenario based on an existing framework I'm using which is forcing me to deal with nested `call_user_func_array` calls. I've got a file with two functions:

```
function their_caller($options)
{
  call_user_func_array('their_callback', $options);
}

function their_callback($options)
{
  call_user_func_array($options[0], $options[1]);
}
```

Then I have another file with a class with and some public methods:

```
namespace FOO;

class MyClass
{
   public function my_caller()
   {
     $operations = array(
       array(
         array($this, 'my_callback'),
         'Hello World'
       )
     );

     their_caller($operations);
   }

   public function my_callback($text)
   {
     print $text;
   }
}
```

When I call `my_caller()` on a new instance of `MyClass`, it calls `their_caller` which then passes an array of arguments containing a reference to `MyClass` (as `$this`) as well as the method `my_callback`.

`their_caller()` then forwards the request to `their_callback` and passes `$options` along.

In `their_callback` I can debug `$options[0]` and see that it's an array containing a reference to `MyClass` and `my_callback`.

I call `get_class_methods()` on `$options[0][0]` in `their_callback` and it will show the list of methods, but for some reason, `call_user_func_array($options[0], $options[1]);` won't call `my_callback` on `MyClass`. I can even call `$options[0][0]->my_callback('HELLO');` and it works.

Unfortunately, I can't modify `their_caller` or `their_callback`. They are part of the framework. Any ideas what's preventing it from working?

Comment: oddly enough, `$options[0][0]->$options[0][1]($options[1]);` works from within `their_callback`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** Your function `their_callback` will receive two arguments.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/808077)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
function their_caller($options)
{
    call_user_func_array('their_callback', $options);
}
//first argument will receive callback
//second argument will receive the text which you want to send as argument.
function their_callback($callback,$option) 
{
    //call_user_func_array should expect second argument as array not string.
    call_user_func_array($callback, array($option));
    //here we have converted `$option` string(Hello World) to array.
}

class MyClass
{
    public function my_caller()
    {
        $operations = array(
        array(
         array($this, 'my_callback'),
                    'Hello World'
                )
            );
        call_user_func_array('their_caller', $operations);
    }

    public function my_callback($text)
    {
        print $text;
    }


} 
$object= new MyClass();
$object->my_caller();
```

Comment: The original parameter passed to `their_caller` is an array of arrays so `their_callback` only receives one parameter (the interior array) which at index 0 is an array with a reference to `MyClass` and `'my_callback'` and at index 1 is the string that I am trying to pass through.

Comment: @Ward The above which you are trying can be achieved in this way also. https://eval.in/808757 here i have changed no of parameters of `their_callback` and changed your `$operations` array, you can try debugging of my code https://eval.in/808668